# Android: Retrieve large Json data from Webservice - get OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, json, web-services

My Android application need to retreive a large data from an external database via webservice. The data is large, arround 60000 records (~ 21MB). I'm using AsyncHttpClient, but I never get back the result in onSuccess methods, caused by OutOfMemoryError.

```
public void getData(final Handler handler) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO)) {
        log.info("PreSynch: Start loading " + objectTypeName);
    }
    (new AsyncHttpClient()).get(presyncUrl, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            responseResult(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray result) {
            responseResult(result);
        }

        private void responseResult(Object result) {
            // Never reach this code
            log.info(objectTypeName + " successfully loaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            // some logs
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            // some logs
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
           // some logs
        }
    });
}
```

The error is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-209
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:114)
            at org.json.JSONArray.put(JSONArray.java:166)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
            at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler.parseResponse(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:216)
            at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:120)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You're trying to load en entire file in an array… you're running out of memory… maybe NOT doing that? or perhaps you can http://downloadmoreram.com ;)

Comment: Have you considered processing it in batches? Say 1000 records at a time? With that amount of data I'd be concerned that it will time out more often than not.

Comment: Can you please tell which type of data you are getting ?

Comment: Apply pagination process to your web services. Depending on where you store the data or displaying the data let say a ListView then apply pagination. For example `http://your_url?page=1` let say on page 1 you have 500 to 100 records then use a widget like button that say `Load More` and then page++ call the same service and so on...

Comment: My data is JSON type, I cannot public an example here, so sorry. Once do paging webservice call, there are many request to the ws, and I do not know what is the best pageSize. It seems that the error occurs while the framework trying to wrap http response string to JsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Android platform, so you have to choose another design, for example paging webservice call.

Comment: Yes I do this way.I mark this answer as no any other answer better.